# Sharing SSL Configuration between apache virtualhosts serving different domains

Tags: ssl, apache2, apache2.4

I have a virtual host for each domain apache2 is serving.

Something like
/etc/apache2/sites-available/1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias www.xyz.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/.../cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/.../privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/.../chain.pem
</VirtualHost

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName qwert.com
    ServerAlias www.qwert.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/.../cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/.../privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/.../chain.pem
</VirtualHost
```

I want to add some SSL settings specifying cipher suite and allowed TLS versions in a way that they are shared between all SSL enabled sites.
That way I can change them centrally instead of editing every single vhost.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

How can I do this centrally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can put you SSL config into a file and include just that file in every vhost.

Fortunately the **Letsencrypt** guys have already created such a file for you: search for options-ssl-apache.conf

```
locate options-ssl-apache.conf
```

example include

```
<VirtualHost ...>
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally here is their example file, the letsencrypt way of making https more secure:

```
SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
SSLHonorCipherOrder     off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
```

this config resulted in an **A+** at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a good bit cleaner than the variables! While the variables allow centralized changes you cannot easily add a new one without touching all config files.

Answer (score 1):

Apache provides the `Define` directive which defines variables that you can use elsewhere.

At the top of my /etc/apache2/apache.conf I define all the SSL settings I want centralized.

```
Define honor_ssl_cipher_order on
Define ssl_protocol "all -SSLv2 -SSLv3"
Define ssl_cipher_suite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

Then in each virtual host I can

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
        SSLProtocol ${ssl_protocol}
        SSLHonorCipherOrder ${honor_ssl_cipher_order}
        SSLCipherSuite "${ssl_cipher_suite}"
</VirtualHost>
```